# java.lang.NullPointerException ao passar para servlet

Tags: java, servlet

Bom dia estou com uma dificuldade em passar os dados de uma jsp para o servlet que vai inserir os dados no banco, fiz três formulários para agendamento e no terceiro ele vai mandar para a servlet porém aparece o erro java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Jsp-----------------------



 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <%
        String cpf = request.getParameter("cpf");
        Cliente c = new Cl

iente();
    try{
       c.setCpf(cpf);
       c.carregar();
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.print("Erro:"+e);
    }

    %>
    <%
    String idservico = request.getParameter("idservico");
    Servico s = new Servico();
    try{
       s.setIdservico(Integer.parseInt(idservico));
       s.carregar();
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.print("Erro:"+e);
    }

    %>
    <%
        String funcionario_cpf = request.getParameter("funcionario_cpf");
    Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
    try{
       f.setCpf(funcionario_cpf);
       f.carregar();
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.print("Erro:"+e);
    }

    %>
    <%
    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    Agendamento a = new Agendamento();
    ArrayList<Agendamento> agendados=new ArrayList<Agendamento>();
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try{
      agendados =  a.listarPorDataCPF( df.parse(data), funcionario_cpf);
    }catch(Exception e){
        out.print("Erro:"+e);
    }

    String[] horarios = {"09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30","13:00","13:30","14:00","14:30","15:00","15:30","16:00","16:30","17:00","17:30"};

    %>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>

    <script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }
    </script> 
        </head>
        <body>
             <%@include file="menu.jsp" %>
            <center>
            <h1>Registrar Agendamento do Cliente</h1>
            <form action="gerenciar_agendamento.do" method="post" id="form_agenda">
                <input type="hidden" name="op" value="inserir"/>
                <b>Cpf :</b><%=c.getCpf() %> /
                <b>Nome do Cliente:</b><%=c.getNome() %><br/>
                <b>Servico:</b> <%=s.getNome() %> (R$<%=s.getPreco() %>)<br/>
                <b>Funcionário</b> <%=f.getNome()%><br/>
                <b>Data:</b> <%=df.parse(data).toString() %><br/>
                <%
                for(int i=0;i<horarios.length;i++){
                    boolean existe=false;
                    for(Agendamento ag:agendados){
                        if(ag.getHora().toString().equals(horarios[i]+":00")){
                            existe=true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(existe){
                        out.print(horarios[i]+" (indisponível)<br/>");
                    }else{
                        out.print(horarios[i]+"<input type='radio' name='horario'/><br/>");
                    }

                }
                %>
                <input type='button' value='Voltar' onclick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
                </select><input type="submit" value="próximo" /><br/>
                <br><br><br><br>
                </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Servlet-----------------

```
String op = request.getParameter("op");
            String idagendamento = request.getParameter("idagendamento");
            String data = request.getParameter("data");
            String hora = request.getParameter("hora");
            String valor = request.getParameter("valor");
            String situacao_pagamento = request.getParameter("situacao_pagamento");
            String situacao_servico = request.getParameter("situacao_servico");
            String cliente_cpf = request.getParameter("cliente_cpf");
            String servico_idservico = request.getParameter("servico_idservico");
            String funcionario_cpf = request.getParameter("funcionario_cpf");            
            try {
                Agendamento a = new Agendamento();
                switch (op) {
                    case "inserir":{
                        if(data.equals("") || data.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo DATA deve ser preenchido!");
                        }else if(hora.equals("") || hora.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo HORA deve ser preenchido!");
                        }else if(valor.equals("") || valor.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo VALOR deve ser preenchido!");                            
                        }else if(situacao_pagamento.equals("") || situacao_pagamento.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo SITUAÇÃO PAGAMENTO deve ser preenchido!");
                        }else if(situacao_servico.equals("") || situacao_servico.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo SITUAÇÃO SERVIÇO deve ser informada!");
                        }else if(cliente_cpf.equals("") || cliente_cpf.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo CLIENTE deve ser selecionado!");
                        }else if(servico_idservico.equals("") || servico_idservico.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo SERVIÇO deve ser selecionado!");
                        }else if(funcionario_cpf.equals("") || funcionario_cpf.isEmpty()){
                            out.print("O campo FUNCIONÁRIO deve ser selecionado!");
                        }else{

                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");                
                            format.format( new Date()   );                    
                            a.setData(format.parse(data));


                            SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                            Date horaa = formatador.parse(hora);
                            Time time = new Time(horaa.getTime());
                            a.setHora(time);  


                            a.setValor(Double.parseDouble(valor));
                            a.setSituacao_pagamento(Boolean.parseBoolean(situacao_pagamento));
                            a.setSituacao_servico(Boolean.parseBoolean(situacao_servico));
                            Cliente c = new Cliente();
                            c.setCpf(cliente_cpf);
                            Servico s = new Servico();
                            s.setIdservico(Integer.parseInt(servico_idservico));
                            Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
                            f.setCpf(funcionario_cpf);
                            a.registrarAgendamento();
                            response.sendRedirect("listar_agendamento.jsp");
                        }
                    }
```

Por favor quem puder me ajudar, estou com essa dificuldade, e essa ocorrendo o erro que falei antes

Saida Glassfish Server--------,

Informações:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Informações:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 9ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Informações:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://DESKTOP-0K4LIKA:8686/jndi/rmi://DESKTOP-0K4LIKA:8686/jmxrmi
Informações:   Dt:Thu Nov 23 00:00:00 BRST 2017

Coloquei o final, pq a única linha que é acrescentada quando o erro ocorre é justamente essa ultima, o erro de java.lang.NullPointerException aparece no navegador quando os dados são redirecionados para o servlet(gerenciar agendamento.do), teste por um out.print depois do case "inserir" e a mensagem apareceu no navegador, os dados que não estão sendo inseridos eu acho

A única mensagem que aparece, erro que é mostrado no navegador é esse:
Erro: java.lang.NullPointerException, mais nada

Comment: Tem várias linhas passíveis de `NullPointerException`. Edita a pergunta e acrescenta a saída do console, por favor

Comment: Amigo, desculpe a ignorância, mas a saída do console o que seria? Pq uso o Netbeans e em saída se for isso o que eu entendi, seria o campo do Glassfish Server?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira, justamente. Mostre a saída do servidor web em que está sendo exibido o erro.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro Erro ocorre ao repassar para o servlet, e ele é mostrado no navegador, fui na saída no GlassFish e não mostra nenhum informação referente ao erro, eu acho que o erro está ao passar as informações dos formulários para o servlet, são 3 jsp ao todo, e em cada um eu fui salvando as escolhas do agendamento  para depois ser repassado ao gerenciar agendamento.do

Comment: @MatheusOliveira, todo erro é gravado no log. Inclusive o erro que aparece no navegador também é salvo no log. Mas ok, se você estiver com dificuldades de encontrar o log correto, copie todo o erro que da no navegador, edite a pergunte e cole o erro.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro eu fiz isso, copiei todo o erro mostrado no navegador que é só aquele que é mostrado

Comment: Vi que você editou a pergunta. Nesse caso, não tem muito como fugir: você tem que ir debugando e vendo se alguma variável contém o valor `null`.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, e todos estão sendo passadas, não sei o que pode ser, mas obrigado